# How Can I FIx This Problem To install Angular Npm?

Tags: angular-cli

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0tGQ.png)

How Can I FIx This Problem To install Angular Npm ?

Comment: Did you try removing the existing file? (See error message)

Answer (score 0):

do `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`. if that doesn'thelp, you will have to remove AppData/Roaming/npm/ng* files manually. Or you can try to `npm i -g @angular/cli --force`